# Offset a pointer in x86 Assembly

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86, att

Code first, problem after.

This code has a block of data I am calling `file`, the block of data is as such:

```
filename
file_pointer
openas
```

Then, in `generateFile` we have `-20(%ebp)` which is a pointer to the first element in the data block, or `-8(%ebp)`.

We call this function inside of `main` and offset the pointer to be able to print out `filename` and `openas`.

```
    .section .data

strLOCK0:
    .asciz "r"

strLOCK1:
    .asciz "hello.txt"

strLOCK2:
    .asciz "%s\n"

strLOCK3:
    .asciz "%d\n"
    .section .text
    .globl _start

_start:
    call main
    movl %eax, %ebx
    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80

    .type generateFile, @function
generateFile:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp

    subl $20, %esp
    movl 12(%ebp), %ecx
    pushl %ecx
    movl 8(%ebp), %ecx
    pushl %ecx
    call fopen
    movl %eax, %ecx
    movl %ecx, -4(%ebp)
    movl 8(%ebp), %ecx
    movl %ecx, -8(%ebp)
    movl -4(%ebp), %ecx
    movl %ecx, -12(%ebp)
    movl 12(%ebp), %ecx
    movl %ecx, -16(%ebp)
    leal -8(%ebp), %ecx
    movl %ecx, -20(%ebp)
    movl -20(%ebp), %ecx
    movl %ecx, %eax
    leave
    ret

    .type main, @function
main:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp

    subl $4, %esp
    movl $strLOCK0, %ecx
    pushl %ecx
    movl $strLOCK1, %ecx
    pushl %ecx
    call generateFile
    movl %eax, %ecx
    movl %ecx, -4(%ebp)
    movl -4(%ebp), %ebx
    movl (%ebx), %ecx
    pushl %ecx
    movl $strLOCK2, %ecx
    pushl %ecx
    call printf
    popl %ebx
    movl -4(%ebp), %ebx
    movl -8(%ebx), %ecx
    pushl %ecx
    movl $strLOCK3, %ecx
    pushl %ecx
    call printf
    popl %ebx
    movl $0, %ecx
    movl %ecx, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

The problem is instead of the expected output of:

```
hello.txt
r
```

Instead I get:

```
hello.txt
-852052
```

I have tried different things such as

```
4(%ebx)
```

When I am getting a value, but it doesn't work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You seem to be returning a pointer to a local variable that is automatically freed by the `leave`. Don't do that. Either allocate space in `main` or use dynamic memory. Your code is basically equivalent to `int* foo() { int x; return &x; }` which is a no-go as `x` is freed as soon as the function returns.

Comment: Separate from that bug, you should `call exit` instead of using `_exit` directly; exit will flush stdio buffers if necessary, and call any atexit functions.  (The most obvious symptom for this program is discarding all output if you redirect to a file, making stdout full buffered)

Comment: The problem with that is that `hello.txt` works fine, just not `r`. @Jester

Comment: That's because you happen to use the `hello.txt` before it gets overwritten. It's still just as wrong, but you got lucky with that.